Running Angular 17 with symfony 6 and docker
I have an angular 17 / symfony 6 project on docker.
The matter is I can't run the app on localhost:4200. I have an "err_connection_reset" on my browser.
However, the angular container is running.
docker ps with angular container running
: https://i.sstatic.net/9nFfo32K.png
The architecture in my IDE and on my development platform :

frontAndBackProjectsFolder

project_client

Dockerfile


project_server

Dockerfile




compose.yaml

Below infos about my conf : 
compose.yaml :
services:

  apache:
    container_name: project_server
    build: ./project_server/
    environment:
      APP_ENV: ${APP_ENV:-dev}
      APP_SECRET: ${APP_SECRET:-xxxxxxxxxxx}
      VERSION: ${VERSION:-1.0.0}
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./project_server/docker-resources/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./project_server/:/var/www/html/project
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    container_name: project_db
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-16}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-xxxx}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-xxxx}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-xxxxx}
      POSTGRES_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST:-172.17.0.1}
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  angular:
    container_name: project_client
    build: ./project_client/
    restart: on-failure
    command: "npm start"
    depends_on:
      - apache
    networks:
      - dev
    volumes:
      - ../project_client/:/var/www/html/project_client/
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

networks:
  dev:

volumes:
  database_data:

Angular Dockerfile :
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json /usr/src/app/

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli \
    npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--open", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port 4200"]

Symfony Dockerfile :
FROM ubuntu:22.04 as project_base

WORKDIR /var/www/html/project/

RUN apt update

RUN apt -y dist-upgrade

RUN mkdir -p /data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /data

RUN mkdir -p /data/docker-files
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /data/docker-files

COPY ./docker-resources/install-requirements.sh /var/www/html/project/docker-resources/
RUN /bin/bash /var/www/html/project/docker-resources/install-requirements.sh

COPY ./docker-resources/apache2-foreground /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground

COPY ./docker-resources/docker-php-entrypoint /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint

COPY ./docker-resources/vhosts/project.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY ./composer.* /var/www/html/project/

RUN composer install --no-scripts

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data ./ /var/www/html/project/

RUN cd /var/www/html/project && \
    composer install --no-scripts --no-cache

EXPOSE 443 80

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN service apache2 restart

FROM project_base as project_dev
COPY ./docker-resources/vhosts/project.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN /bin/bash /var/www/html/project/docker-resources/install-requirements-dev.sh

Could you please help me figure out what am I missing ?
Thanks a lot !!
EDIT : 
Angular container running fine: [https://i.sstatic.net/Z45cVWzm.png] 
NGINX in compose.yaml: [https://i.sstatic.net/fzr4HRr6.png]

Since my setup looks a little bit different I can only do some educated guesses. But maybe some things will help:

Try adding the following to angular in your .yml

    expose:
      - "4200"


In your Angular Dockerfile I can see you added the port option like this "--port 4200" but the host option as two array values. Maybe try to do the host option like the port one as well "--host 0.0.0.0" or the port like the host one.

Your angular volumes seems off. Is it intended to look like that?

If you run the docker, does the angular container return an error? Maybe it is failing while building, so the app isnt available.

Try changing the angular command from npm start to command: npm start --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check



Maybe some of those Ideas can help you. 
If it still doesnt work I could help you get it running with my setup. 
That would be on Linux with Traefik

Thanks for your answer. So I followed the 5 of your advices. But it still doesn't work and there is no error at building stage and either when I run docker. I also tried to add nginx to serve the angular part but it doesn't help. Yes, it would be awesome if you could help me some more !
